# Access shared library and other contract's functions

Tags: solidity, library

I have Contract A, Contract NFT, and Library. Library will have some NFT info that both Contract A and NFT needs.

NFT contract has the following:

```
contract NFT is ERC1155 {
mapping(string => Library.NFTInfo) public nft;

function viewNFTInfo(string calldata _uri) public view returns(Library.NFTInfo memory) {        
        return Library.viewInfo(nft, _uri);
    }
}
```

In the library:

```
library Library{
    struct NFTInfo{
        uint256 collectId;
        uint256 totalSupply;
    }


    function viewInfo( mapping(string => NFTInfo) storage self, string calldata _uri)
        internal
        returns (NFTInfo storage)
    {
        return self[_uri];
    }
}
```

In Contract A I have a function that needs to look up the info on this NFT and do something, for example burn it.

```
contract A is ERC20 {
    IERC1155 public nfts;

    constructor () {
        nfts = IERC1155(nftAddr);
    }
    Library.NFTInfo memory collect = nfts.viewInfo(ipfs); //<--- here is the error
        nfts.burn(anAddr, collect.collectId, amount);

    }
}
```

In Contract A, it needs to look up what is in `NFT.viewInfo()`, but I am getting:
`function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function`

**Why is it unable to see the function?**

Comment: In summary, Are you trying to call the viewInfo() function from your 'A' contract?

Comment: @Kerry99 yes I am. I need both contract to access it with same info.

Comment: Ok, but why do you use nfts variable to call viewInfo() function? You should use Library.viewInfo({parameters})